# $P[A > B, A > C]$, where $A$, $B$, and $C$ are i.i.d. random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, independence

Let $A$, $B$, and $C$ be i.i.d. random variables. What is the probability $P[A > B, A > C]$? Does the independence of $A$, $B$, and $C$ imply the independence of the events $A > B$ and $A > C$? In other words, does it hold that $P[A > B, A > C] = P[A > B] P[A > C]$? If not, why? Providing an example would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the simplest example I could think of.

If $A$, $B$, and $C$ are independent coin tosses with heads 1 and tails 0 then $$P(A>B, A>C)=1/8$$ since this only happens if A=1 and B and C are both 0, which is one of eight possible outcomes, but $$P(A>B)=1/4=P(A>C)$$ since this only happens if $A=1$ and $B$ or $C=0$, which is only one of four possible outcomes, so $${1\over 8}=P(A>B, A>C)\neq P(A>B)\times P(A>C)={1\over 16}.$$

To look at it another way, $P(A>C)=1/4$, but if we know that $A>B$ already, then we know that $A=1$ and $B=0$, so $P(A>C|A>B),$ the *conditional probability* that $A>C$ given $A>B$, is just the probability that $C=0$, since we already know that if $A>B$ then $A=1$ and $B=0$, and $C$'s probability is independent, so $$P(A>C|A>B)=P(C=0)=\frac12.$$ So
$$
P(A>B,A>C)=P(A>C|A>B)P(A>B)=\frac12\times\frac14.
$$

Comment: Nice example. Thanks.

Comment: +1 Nice -- great counterexample

Answer (score 3):

> Does the independence of A, B, and C imply the independence of the events A>B and A>C?

No.  The event of $A>B$ is evidence that $A$ is large, thus making it more likely that $A>C$ too.

---

Rather, the iid nature of the random variables introduces the following symmetries:

- consider that these six mutually exclusive events are equally probable to each other: $$\rm A>B>C~,~ A>C>B~,~ B>A>C~,~ B>C>A~,~ C>A>B~,~ C>B>A$$
- consider that these six mutually exclusive events are equally probable to each other: $$\rm A>B=C~,~ A>C=B~,~ B>A=C~,~ B>C=A~,~ C>A=B~,~ C>B=A$$
- consider that these six mutually exclusive events are equally probable to each other: $$\rm A=B>C~,~ A=C>B~,~ B=A>C~,~ B=C>A~,~ C=A>B~,~ C=B>A$$
- Then there is this event $A=B=C$.  This and all the above events are mutually exclusive (aka disjoint).
- Of course, things are much simpler if the random variables are continuous, as that vanishes the chances of ties.  You need some more information about the distribution if the variables are discrete.

Comment: Why not that B is small? Then it's more likely that B<C?

Comment: @Bey .... which has naught to do with the dependence of the events $\{A>B\}$ and $\{A>C\}$.

Comment: it seems there is a symmetry you aren't considering, that $A>B$ doesn't tell us that $A$ is large, just that it is larger than $B$ which may be really, really small .. so I'm not sure if it makes $A>C$ more likely.

Comment: The information the condition $A>B$ provides, makes the conditional probability for $A>C$ greater than the unconditional probability.

Comment: Intuitively, I agree with you but this has not been shown.